# Why SQL Job Scheduling is not moving all the records some time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, job-scheduling

I set the job schedule on daily basis. When I check the records on the next day, the records were not moved completely on someday. I don't know why.

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[F_ItemDailySalesParent]
(
[ItemID]
  ,[StoreID]
  ,[ItemLookupCode]
  ,[DepartmentID]
  ,[CategoryID]
  ,[SupplierID]
  ,[Time]
  ,[Qty]
  ,[ExtendedPrice]
  ,[ExtendedCost]
)
SELECT 
[ItemID]
  ,[StoreID]
  ,[ItemLookupCode]
  ,[DepartmentID]
  ,[CategoryID]
  ,[SupplierID]
  ,[Time]
  ,[Qty]
  ,[ExtendedPrice]
  ,[ExtendedCost]
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JC_ItemDailySalesParent]
where time=convert(Date,getdate()-1)
```

Total records found on **[JC_ItemDailySalesParent] = 21027** and total records on **[F_ItemDailySalesParent] = 18741** on 06-March-2017

> If you think i might have missed some column or something else!.. Then I will execute the same query by changing where condition to `where time=convert(Date,getdate())`. Then it's executed the complete record without missing.
>
> **Note:** Both tables are job schedule. `[JC_ItemDailySalesParent]` table will run at 2 am. `F_ItemDailySalesParent` will run at early morning 6 o ck.

Don't ask me why two tables with same record. That's for different purpose.

Thanks,

Comment: I would get away from using `getdate()-1` and explicitly use `DATEADD()` function. You need to provide some sample data and expected output. Check the `SYSDATETIME()` to see how it compares to your local time. Check to make sure records actually exist for the condition in your `WHERE` clause. This is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @scsimon There is no chance to change the system date. because both jobs and tables are located in same server

Comment: @jarlh done....

Answer (score 0):

Always try to have a unique identifier in the table. Assuming combination of ItemID, StoreID, ItemLookupCode, DepartmentID, CategoryID, SupplierID, Time are unique:

```
INSERT INTO HQWebMatajer.dbo.F_ItemDailySalesParent
( ItemID
, StoreID
, ItemLookupCode
, DepartmentID
, CategoryID
, SupplierID
, Time
, Qty
, ExtendedPrice
, ExtendedCost
)
SELECT ItemID
  , StoreID
  , ItemLookupCode
  , DepartmentID
  , CategoryID
  , SupplierID
  , Time
  , Qty
  , ExtendedPrice
  , ExtendedCost
FROM HQMatajer.dbo.JC_ItemDailySalesParent src
LEFT JOIN  HQWebMatajer.dbo.F_ItemDailySalesParent tgt
    ON tgt.ItemID = src.ItemID
    AND tgt.StoreID = src.StoreID
    AND tgt.ItemLookupCode = src.ItemLookupCode
    AND tgt.DepartmentID = src.DepartmentID
    AND tgt.CategoryID = src.CategoryID
    AND tgt.SupplierID = src.SupplierID
    AND tgt.Time = src.Time
WHERE tgt.ItemID IS NULL;
```